# REST RQL Java Implementation

Tags: java, rest, search-engine

Is there any java implementation of "RQL" (Resource Query Language), there is an implementation of "FIQL" (Feed Item Query Language) [here](http://cxf.apache.org/docs/jax-rs-search.html) but it is part of CXF, so my questions are :

1. Can I use the FIQL engine of CXF implementation separably from using CXF, in case I'm using Spring MVC
2. Is there implementation of RQL
3. RQL vs FIQL

Answer (score 5):

R-SQL parser is partial implementation of FIQL:

- https://github.com/jirutka/rsql-parser
- https://github.com/jirutka/rsql-hibernate

Answer (score 0):

Thanks Jakub, I have modified rsql-parser to support also RQL queries by adding

```
logical AND: "&" and OR: "|" ;
comparison operators: equal to : "=eq=", not equal to : "=ne=",
IN array list: "=in=" and NOT IN array list "=out="
```

I added also `=in=` and `=out=` operator support to rsql-hibernate.
I have committed my modifications to github....

Comment: FYI, take a look at fresh [2.0.M1](https://github.com/jirutka/rsql-parser) – completely rewritten, includes =in= and =out= operators and it’s extensible; you can simply define a custom FIQL-like operators. ;)